# awscli describe-instances, unable to sort query when there are multiple reservations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am attempting to sort a list of instance IDs by launch time (so older instances are on top), but I seem to be having problems because of the way that the output of 'describe-instances' is separated in multiple 'Reservations'.

The following seems to work when a single reservation is specified:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id file://instancelist.json --query "Reservations[0] | sort_by(Instances, &LaunchTime)[].InstanceId"
[
    "i-0ea6fe5asda50d5ea"
]

$ aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id file://instancelist.json --query "Reservations[1] | sort_by(Instances, &LaunchTime)[].InstanceId"
[
    "i-027c72g748aae21e2", 
    "i-086b329e39ee20b86", 
    "i-0035dd291e67e141c"
]
```

But if I try to do the same for multiple Reservations, I see:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id file://instancelist.json --query "Reservations[*] | sort_by(Instances, &LaunchTime)[].InstanceId"

In function sort_by(), invalid type for value: None, expected one of: ['array'], received: "null"

$ aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id file://instancelist.json --query "Reservations[0:1] | sort_by(Instances, &LaunchTime)[].InstanceId"

In function sort_by(), invalid type for value: None, expected one of: ['array'], received: "null"
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try some variant of the following, which retrieves all instances for all reservations, then flattens that intermediate result, then sorts by `LaunchTime` (aliased to `time`):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*][].{id:InstanceId,time:LaunchTime} \
    | sort_by([], &time)"
```

The output will look like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "i-0d9876e0df933a123",
        "time": "2019-07-09T11:52:11.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "i-0d1234d5c35fff987",
        "time": "2019-07-10T13:50:14.000Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped. This seems to work for me '$ aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id file://instancelist.json --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*][] | sort_by([], &LaunchTime)[].InstanceId" '

Answer (score 1):

```
#Try below ones:
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[PrivateIpAddress,InstanceId,InstanceType,LaunchTime,Tags[?Key==`Name`]| [0].Value] | sort_by(@, &[3]) ' --output table
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[PrivateIpAddress,InstanceId,InstanceType,LaunchTime,Tags[?Key==`Name`]| [0].Value] | sort_by(@, &[3]) ' --output json
```